# Excel 2010 match multiple criteria and return multiple rows and columns without using an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to be able to match multiple criteria and return multiple rows and columns without using an array in Excel 2010. I am currently using the below for a single criteria and am able to return multiple rows and columns without using an array:

```
=INDEX($A$7:$AO$4500, SMALL(INDEX(($AN$1=$B$7:$B$4500)*(MATCH(ROW($B$7:$B$4500), ROW($B$7:$B$4500)))+($AN$1<>$B$7:$B$4500)*1048577, 0, 0),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1))
```

Table is in `A7:AO4500`

```
AN1 = Today()
Row B = Due Date
Row AZ = Ship Date (looking for "")
```

Comment: I think the common response to Excel questions is to ask to post an example of the data you're working with.

Comment: That comment is just a mess. Please edit your question and add the information to it. Please use the correct formatting tags.

Comment: For better understanding provide the LINK of the Sheet or upload the Sample Data along with the Criteria list.

Answer (score 0):

*Since, no sample Data has been provide therefore I've decide to use my Sample Data to extract more than one records on multiple criteria lookup.*

**NB:** *Only an Array Formula can do this.*

Check the Screen Shot.

[image]

The Formula I've used is,

=INDEX($A$36:$C$45,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$34,$B$36:$B$45)*COUNTIF($F$34, $C$36:$C$45),ROW($A$36:$C$45)-MIN(ROW($A$36:$C$45))+1),ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1))

The Formula is using **Criteria in Cells E34 & F34 are 100 & 50.**

**Note ,** Multiplication sign used to **connect both COUNTIF** is working as AND.

*Below the Database, you can find two filtered Rows matching the Criteria.*

**I do believe this example helps you and you can easily extend the scope of the exercise.**

**NB:** *If you are fixed with Non-Array Formula solution, I can suggest you Tricks with Advance  Filter.*